# iAds ADBanner disappear when back button is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad, navigationcontroller

i have a navigation controller with a depth of 3 viewcontrollers. root, one, two 
i want to add an ADBannerview and I followed the iAdsSuite sample code from apple.
i added to all of my viewcontrollers.
the adbanner loads at first then it is fine if i navigate to one and two.
but if i click back button from two and one, the banner is not loading anymore.
it is working root --> one --> two but it's not working two --> one --> root.
anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I endup implementing ADBannerView in appDelegate. Use custom delegate method to resize the UITableview of one and two. Don't know it is the right way to do...

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to diagnose the problem without looking at the source, however this sounds like a memory management issue to me. Something might be getting released when it shouldn't, or perhaps isn't being retained.